# C Programming - File io parsing strings using sscanff

Tags: c, linux, unix, argv

I am trying to do the following the C programming language, any help or if you can finish the code I will be greatly appreciated:

I am trying to write a program in C programming language that uses file io, that will parse through the words using sscanf function and output each word in all the sentences inside a txt document (bar.txt). Here is the instructions.

> Write a program that opens the file bar.txt name the program "reader". Pass a parameter to indicate lines to read. Read all the lines in the file based on the parameter 'lines' into a buffer and using sscanf parse all the words of the sentences into different string* variables. Print each of the words to the screen followed by a carriage return. You can hardwire filename (path of bar.xt) or use option to enter filename.

This is the txt file (bar.txt) i am working with:

****bar.txt****

```
this is the first sentence
this is the 2nd sentence
this is the 3rd sentence
this is the 4th sentence
this is the 5th sentence
```

****end of file: bar.txt****

usage of argv: Usage: updater [-f "filename"] 'lines'

-f is optional (if not provided have a hardwired name from previous program 2 (bar.txt))
'lines' integer from 1 to 10 (remember the files has 5-10 strings from previous program)
a sample input example for the input into the program is:

./reader -f bar.txt 1

OUTPUT:

```
Opening file "bar.txt"
File Sentence 1 word 1 = this
File Sentence 1 word 2 = is
File Sentence 1 word 3 = the
File Sentence 1 word 4 = first
File Sentence 1 word 5 = sentence
```

***another example***

./reader -f bar.txt 5

OUTPUT:

```
File Sentence 5 word 1 = this
File Sentence 5 word 2 = is
File Sentence 5 word 3 = the
File Sentence 5 word 4 = 5th
File Sentence 5 word 5 = sentence
```

Examples of commands:

```
./reader -f bar.txt 5
./reader -f bar.txt 2
./reader -f bar.txt 7
./reader 2
./reader 5
./reader 8
./reader 11
```

this is the code that I have so far please fix the code to show the desired output:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCHAR 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file;
    char string[MAXCHAR];
    char* filename = "c:\\cprogram\\fileio-activity\\bar.txt";
    int integer = argv[3][0] - 48;
    int i; //for loops

    if (argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] == 'f')
    {
        file = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (file == NULL){
            printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
            return 1;
        }
        while (fgets(string, MAXCHAR, file) != NULL)
            printf("%s", string);
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Accessing `argv[3]` causes undefined behavior when you only pass 1 argument, as in the last 4 examples. You're also never using the filename after `-f`.

Comment: `argv[3][0] - 48` will only work if they enter a 1-digit number. You should parse the entire argument as an integer, using a function like `atoi()`

Comment: You need to show your attempt at using sscanf if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the filename from `argv` if they use the `-f` option. And you need to get the number of lines from a different argument depending on whether this option was supplied.

Use `strcmp()` to compare strings, rather than testing each character separately. And use `atoi()` to convert the `lines` argument to an integer, since your method only works for single-digit numbers.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCHAR 1000

function usage() {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: reader [-f filename] lines\n");
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file;
    char string[MAXCHAR];
    char* filename = "c:\\cprogram\\fileio-activity\\bar.txt";
    int integer;
    int i; //for loops

    if (argc < 2) {
        usage();
    }

    # Process arguments
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-f") == 0)
    {
        if (argc < 4) {
            usage();
        }
        filename = argv[2];
        integer = atoi(argv[3]);
    } else {
        integer = atoi(argc[1]);
    }

    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s\n",filename);
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(string, MAXCHAR, file) != NULL)
        printf("%s", string);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Barmar already answered, for the further steps in completing the assignment:

Splitting a string into separate words is usually called *tokenization*, and we normally use [`strtok()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) for this.  There are several ways how one can use [`sscanf()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) to do it.  For example:

1. Use `sscanf(string, "%s %s %s", word1, word2, word3)` with however many word buffers you might need. (If you use e.g. `char word1[100]`, then use `%99s`, to avoid buffer overrun bugs.  One character must be reserved for the end-of-string character `\0`.)

   The return value of `sscanf()` tells you how many words it copied to the word buffers.  However, if `string` contains more than the number of words you specified, the extra ones are lost.

   If the exercise specifies the maximum length of strings, say *N*, then you know there can be at most *N*/2+1 words, each of maximum length *N*, because each consecutive pair of words must be separated by at least one space or other whitespace character.
2. Use `sscanf(string + off, " %s%n", word, &len)` to obtain each word in a loop.  It will return 1 (with `int len` set to a positive number) for each new word, and `0` or `EOF` when `string` starting at `off` does not contain any more words.

   The idea is that for each new word, you increment `off` by `len`, thus examining the *rest* of `string` in each iteration.
3. Use `sscanf(string + off, " %n%*s%n", &start, &end)` with `int start, end` to obtain the range of positions containing the next word.  Set `start = -1` and `end = -1` before the call, and repeat as long as `end > start` after the call.  Advance to next word by adding `end` to `off`.

   The beginning of the next word (when `start >= 0`) is then `string + start`, and it has `end - start` characters.

   To "emulate" `strtok()` behaviour, one can temporarily save the terminating character (which can be whitespace or the end of string character) by using e.g. `char saved = string[off + end];`, then replace it with an end-of-string character, `string[off + end] = '\0';`, so that `(string + start)` is a pointer to the word, just like `strtok()` returns.  Before the next scan, one does `string[off + end] = saved;` to restore the saved character, and `off += end;` to advance to the next word.

The first one is the easiest, but is the least useful in practical programs.  (It works fine, but we do not usually know beforehand the string length and word count limitations.)

The second one is very useful when you have *alternate patterns* you can try for the next "word" or item; for example, when reading 2D or 3D vectors (points in a plane, or in three-dimensional space), you can support multiple different formats from `<1 2 3>` to `[1,2,3]` to `1 2 3`, by trying to parse the most complicated/longest first, and trying the next one, until one of them works.  (If none of them work, then the input is in error, of course.)

The third one is most useful in that it describes essentially how `strtok()` works, and what its side effects are.  (It's saved character is hidden internally as a static variable.)